# How to print values using form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to print form data values using formdata.entries function? Reason being I have multiple ng-repeat.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Coupon Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="coupon in coupons" class="{'fadeOut' : coupon.done}">
            <td>{{coupon.title}} <span class="fa fa-close margin-left" ng-click="deletecoupon($index)"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div name="couponsFrm">
    <input type="text" name="newcoupon" ng-model="newcoupon" required />
    <button ng-disabled="couponsFrm.$invalid" ng-click="addcoupon()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Coupon</button>
</div>
```

And this is the controller

```
$scope.submitTrType = function(){
    var formData = new FormData("#my-form");
    console.log(formData);
    formData.append('key1', 'value1');
    formData.append('key2', 'value2');
    for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing new FormData("#my-form") to new FormData()

Comment: Why I can't see forms and submit button which is calling function named as `submitTrType`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
for (var value of formData.values()) {
                alert(value);
           }
```

Comment: the values are not static! they are coming dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You have to define ng-model for every text box in the form. Then you can access these text box values in your "submitTrType " function by using $scope.textBox1 (example variable name).

Answer (score 0):

You will not get values of the form element using `FormData`. If you really need it then you can do something like this

```
var formElements = document.forms['my-form'].elements['nameOfFormElements'].value;
```

or use JQuery or javascript to get the form values. This is because the `FormData` object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using `XMLHttpRequest`. Its primarily intended for use in sending form data. The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

And if you try to use `key/value` pair of `formData` then for this

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("phone", "1234567890");
formData.append("phone", "9876543210");
formData.get("phone");
```

This will only return the first `phone` for that key, in this case it will return '1234567890'. And this may behave unusual in different browsers.

Comment: FYI values are coming dynamic

Comment: They might have something in common like name or other attributes like all elements are input type or something like that.